# Issueswith React-Navigation and Fetch()

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

Essentially: I am using react-navigation to navigate between two screens in my app. 
This in principle works fine, I can use the navigation buttons to navigate between screens.

However, I am running in to a problem I am completely unable to troubleshoot because no useful error information is generated.

Basically, each page of the app needs to use fetch() to pull data when it is mounted, and upon first mount of the component it works as expected. The issues arises after moving between pages.

Essentially it seems to me that fetch() simply stops working after I navigate between screens. Basically I need to be able to make some POST and GET requests, however this simply does not work. Far as I can tell the calls to fetch() don't even fire.

If I look at what data is communicated by my app and my server in Wireshark, I can can see that when the components first mount, they communicate just fine over TLS1.2.
Then when navigate to one page and navigate back, NO data is sent or received.

So my question is, why does switching between app pages seem to make React-native not want to execute fetch() commands any more?

Code will be provided upon request, but I don't think seeing it will help much since the issue seems unrelated to my specific code. The code works fine, just as long as I never switch between app pages.

Comment: It's hard to understand all your problems with words alone. Show me the code and explain the problem.

Comment: Like I mentioned, the problem is that after switching between two pages in a react-native app, then fetch() stops working. Do you want me to upload a couple of thousands line of code and try to read through them to identify an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite changing no lines of code.
The code now seems to work.